# Tkinter - My custom icon "disturbs" the Top Level window when it opens

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

when I opened my Top Level window, I always saw an annoying and weird behaviour.. at the end I realized that it was because of my custom icon.

below an exaple code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("494x410+370+100")
        self.parent.title("My Software - WITH ICON")
        self.parent.iconbitmap("icon.ico")

        Button = ttk.Button(self.parent, text="open a new widnow", command=self.OpenNewWindow)
        Button.place(x=16, y=16)

    def OpenNewWindow(self):
        self.obj = NewWindow(self)

class NewWindow:
    def __init__(self, mw):
        self.window, self.mw = Toplevel(mw.parent), mw
        self.window.geometry("200x150+360+200")
        self.window.title("New Window")
        self.window.iconbitmap("icon.ico") # it creates the issue..
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

        self.window.focus()
        self.mw.parent.attributes('-disabled', 1)
        self.window.transient(mw.parent)
        self.window.grab_set()
        self.mw.parent.wait_window(self.window)

    def on_close(self):
        self.mw.parent.attributes('-disabled', 0)
        self.window.destroy()

def main():
    app=MainWindow()
    app.parent.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

to make it clear where is the issue, I create a GIF:

[image]

here we have two softwares, "without icon.py" and "with icon.py". they are the same, but the first one doesn't use my custom icon for his second window.

as you can see, if I run "with icon.py" the second window will be always affected by something when I will open it, but for "without icon.py" this "something" doesn't exist.

what is the issue? the software opens his second window, focus the root one (it's the issue), and then focus the second window again. you can see it clearly from the GIF.

how can I solve the issue? and why with the default icon this weird behaviour doesn't happen?

Comment: Do you still have the same issue after commenting out `self.window.transient(mw.parent)`?

Comment: mm.. good question. without the `self.window.transient(mw.parent)` instruction, the issue seems solved, but in this way, my second window doesn't flash anymore when I try to click on the parent one. keep in mind that with the default icon I don't need to delete this instruction.